# Example of a concave function that grows faster than a polynomial function as $x$ goes to $-\infty$ and have larger values as well

Tags: polynomials, examples-counterexamples

Let us think of a polynomial function $-x^3$.

Is there a concave function that is positive and grows faster than this polynomial function as $x$ goes to $-\infty$?

I cannot find a good explicit example myself, though I can vaguely imagine one...Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There cannot be such a function. If $f$ is positive and concave then for $x < -1$ 
$$
 0 < f(x) \le L(x)
$$
where $L$ is the secant line joining $(-1, f(-1))$ and $(0, f(0))$, which means that $f$ grows at most linear for $x \to -\infty$.

Comment: Actually I was triggered into asking this question to solve the problem in this link

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3572270/weak-convergence-combined-with-a-e-convergence-imply-something

Comment: Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: @Keith: I am afraid that is not my area of expertise.